# Unable to load ListView items using Itemsource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a `ListView` that is enclosed inside a [dragablz](http://dragablz.net/) tabs plugin:

```
<dragablz:TabablzControl Opacity="0.8" BorderBrush="#FF4C589C"  Margin="10,49,10,10" Background="#FF402D61" TabStripPlacement="Left">
           
            <dragablz:TabablzControl.InterTabController>
                <dragablz:InterTabController />
            </dragablz:TabablzControl.InterTabController>
            <TabItem Header="Texts">
                <WrapPanel x:Name="textContainer"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Files">
                <ListView SelectionMode="Extended" x:Name="files" Background="#FF19174B"  AllowDrop="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="files_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="files_MouseMove">
                    <ListView.DataContext>
                        <local:FileItem/>
                    </ListView.DataContext>

                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel>
                                <local:FileItem/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                
            </TabItem>
        </dragablz:TabablzControl>
```

The caller window calls `InitItems()` method of the window containing this `ListView` populating it with user controls of type `FileItem`:

```
public int InitItems()
        {
            FileOps.UserDataCollection userData = Utility.userData;
            if (userData != null && userData.userData != null && userData.userData.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (UserData ud in userData.userData)
                {
                    switch (ud.DataType)
                    {
                        case "file": _FileItems.Add(new FileItem(ud));
                            break;
                        default: break;
                    }
                }
                files.ItemsSource = FileItems;
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

`FileItems` and `_FileItems` are defined as:

```
private ObservableCollection<FileItem> _FileItems = new ObservableCollection<FileItem>();
        public ObservableCollection<FileItem> FileItems
        {
            get
            {
                return _FileItems;
            }
        }
```

Which are getting data successfully when checked using a breakpoint on line `files.ItemsSource = FileItems;` in `InitItems()` method.

But the problem is that the `ListView` is not showing the user controls. Please tell me what I am missing? I am just a beginner in WPF.

Comment: Drop `<ListView.ItemTemplate>` and `<ListView.DataContext>`. The `<local:FileItem/>` in the ItemTemplate has no relation to the `FileItem` in the ItemsSource collection. That said, you shouldn't have UI elements in the ItemsSource collection at all. Instead the collection would contain items that represent the data to be displayed by a `FileItem` UI element. Setting the DataContext of the ListView like you did neither makes sense nor is in any way necessary here.

Comment: @Clemens Ok I will drop `<ListView.DataContext>` coz it was added accidentally. But `<ListView.ItemTemplate>` is for displaying items in icon view like Windows Explorer. Each item is wrapped inside a `<DockPanel>`. This item is a user control `FileItem`. So if you say that UI elements must not be in `ItemsSource`, then how should I add them in list view? Or do I need to use `ListView.Items.Add()` instead of `ItemsSource`?

Comment: If you have a FileItem (UserControl?) in the ItemTemplate, its properties should be bound to a view model file item class in the collection. See here: [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx).